# Count items in ViewResult or ActionResult - MVC Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to unit test the controllers method results with the following code

```
StoreController test = new MvcMusicStore.Controllers.StoreController(); 
ActionResult result = test.Index(); 
ViewResult p = (ViewResult)result;
```

result and p shows 10 items in the model when debugging but it seems that I can not do Count or foreach to check how many records are returned as both objects are dictionary.
How can this be done?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`ViewResult.Model` is of type `object` you have to cast it to the collection type first to get a count.

For example, if you're passing the list of integers as a model to your view, you can get the count this way:

```
var model = p.Model;
var list = model as List<int>();
var count = list.Count;
```

Comment: Thanks so much,worked  like a charm. I have another action which receives a parameter and returns 1 single record (id, name, dateofBirth), how can I assert or check against some of its values?

Comment: @user3759591 cast to the type of that single record. `model as SingleRecord`

Comment: TK, I did the following

Comment: Argh, all I needed was the cast... Thanks very much!

Comment: @Reisclef no problem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a model of `IEnumerable<DataType>` and you want to get this model in a unit test, you have to cast the `result.ViewData.Model` to your type and then do your Assertions:

```
var test = new StoreController();
var result = test.Index() as ViewResult;
var data = (IEnumerable<ModelType>) result.ViewData.Model;
Assert.AreEqual(10, data.Count());
```

Reference: https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/unit-testing/creating-unit-tests-for-asp-net-mvc-applications-cs (Listing 4)

Comment: Thanks for all of you. I added another unit test to validate a an action as follows

Comment: Thanks for all of you. I added another unit test to validate a an action as follows 
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
        { 
        ....
        ....
         return View(model);
        }

In my unit test, I have 
AccountController test = new AccountController();
RegisterModel rm = new RegisterModel { UserName = Rand2, Email = Rand2 + "sddsds@free.fr", Password = Rand2+ "?123K", ConfirmPassword = Rand2 + "?123K" };
    var view = test.Register(rm);

Comment: I wanted to assert thar rm is a View, but when debugging I see that it is of type RedirectToRouteResult and not View and of course when I do 
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(view, typeof(RedirectToRouteResult));

the unit test succeeds, why is this and why it is of this type, what is the relation between View type and RedirectToRouteResult?

Comment: Would you please ask this as a seperate question please? Comments are not a discussion forum